# Under what circumstances may c's write()-function write less data than requested?

Tags: java, c, linux

I'm writing to a file in chunks of about 10b to 16 000b, when suddenly every chunk gets cut off at around 4050 bytes (specifically, 4050, 4051 and 4074 bytes, in that order). This means subsequent writes will overwrite data that ought to have been written, messing up my data. Any chunk under 4050b is written out fine.

Unfortunately, I can't reproduce it. All I have is the messed up file, so I'm debugging looking for something that would cause this.

Debugging it, I realize c's write() function gets called under the hood (this is Java code, FileChannel.write(), but the standard library calls c's write and only checks that bytes written > 0), and that the docs for it do not guarantee that it will write out all data asked for, only that it will tell you how much was written.

I don't check bytes written back in Java land (but I do get it, the function signature is almost the exact same), so the fix is dead simple. However, since I can't reproduce this, I don't know that I've fixed the actual problem. So therefore I'm hoping some c guru can tell me either that I'm smoking crack, or that there are legitimate circumstances where write() will be unable to write more than about 4050 bytes at a time.

This is running on a 64-bit Linux Kernel, version 3.0.0-26.

Edit: To expand as per comments below:

I'm writing to a normal file system file. I'm not sure what non-blocking means in this context, I'm not using callbacks or anything, but explicitly telling the OS to flush to disk is not done for each chunk. The file is opened using Java's RandomAccessFile, 'rw' mode.

Comment: What do you mean you can't reproduce it? Does the problem not happen anymore?

Comment: Can you add more details on where you are writing to and what chances are that destination file descriptor is in non-blocking mode?

Comment: If your code is in Java, you should ask about the Java API's behavior. For example, if you're using `java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write()`, the entire amount of data will be written (at least to the buffer - you would need to `flush()` or `close()` to ensure the buffer has been written) or an exception will be thrown.  That specification is independent of how the underlying system call operates.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I'm using FileChannel.write(), the implementation of which, on unix, delegates directly to c's write(). The contract of the two are about the same, but I figured it would be easier to ask for the contract of c's write, since java just delegates there.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the `FileChannel` rather than just calling the `write()` method on the `RandomAccessFile` object?

Comment: @MichaelBurr yes, there are alternative FileChannel subclasses in the system to support IO on other resources (I know, there should be a separate interface for that abstraction, but that is an unrelated issue I think). In this case, all IO is through a normal FileChannel class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `man 2 write`:

```
   The number of bytes written may be less than  count  if,  for  example,
   there  is  insufficient space on the underlying physical medium, or the
   RLIMIT_FSIZE resource limit is encountered (see setrlimit(2)),  or  the
   call was interrupted by a signal handler after having written less than
   count bytes.  (See also pipe(7).)
```

From `man 2 setrlimit`:

```
   RLIMIT_FSIZE
          The maximum size of files that the process may create.  Attempts
          to extend a file beyond this  limit  result  in  delivery  of  a
          SIGXFSZ  signal.   By default, this signal terminates a process,
          but a process can catch this signal instead, in which  case  the
          relevant  system  call  (e.g., write(2), truncate(2)) fails with
          the error EFBIG.
```

These limits can be seen using the following commands:

```
ulimit -Sf
ulimit -Hf
```

Or by using this C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

int main()
{
    struct rlimit rl;
    if (getrlimit(RLIMIT_FSIZE, &rl) == 0) {
        printf("%d %d\n", rl.rlim_cur, rl.rlim_max);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: %d\n", errno);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This hints towards this being a cause, but as per the examples, it wouldn't explain the 4050 bytes-at-a-time behavior. If it were disk space, it should just stop letting me write, right?

Comment: @jakewins, a signal handler can kick in at any moment. The buffer size on which you start noticing this is just the point where the writes are sufficiently often interrupted with your combination of soft- and hardware. All of this shouldn't be a problem if you'd use the `write` call properly. Check its return (and eventually `errno`) and reiterate until you have written everything. It is supposed to work like that and not otherwise.

Comment: Agreed, and I will definitely modify the code to do that. But I'm still curious about the apparent pattern of getting cut off right on or after 4050 bytes? Could there be a signal handler that picks up on the amount written and triggers after? It appears to be a race condition of some kind, since the number isn't exactly 4050 and differs slightly each time.

Answer (score 4):

From the Linux Programmer's Manual, on write(1): "write()  writes  **up  to**  count  bytes to the file..."

How much is written depends on what you are writing to and whether you are using synchronous writes or not.

E.g. if it's a pipe och a socket, you can't write more than a pipe/socket buffer full (in synchronous mode: More than what's available in the buffer).

Comment: That points towards this being the case - I'm writing to a normal file on disk though, what could cause the OS to suddenly cap writes to a file by a buffer of approximately 4050 bytes?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to reproduce the problem is to have a slow consumer.  This will cause the send buffer to be almost full when you call write() meaning not all the data you give it can be written.  You can reduce the send and receiver buffer sizes to make this problem more obvious.